# Play a sound to the microphone input

Tags: windows, audio, microphone

I am looking for a program for Microsoft Windows that can play a sound to the microphone input. For example, I have a sound file `hello.mp3`: I would like to play this sound file so that Windows "thinks" it comes from the microphone.

Any price, license is fine.

Use case: I want to benchmark speech recognition programs and I would like to test them with the same sound inputs.

Comment: In case you don't find anything like that, you could "let Alexa talk to Siri": Record the wanted intput (e.g. on a smartphone), then play it back to the mike of the computer you're running the speech recognition on.

Answer (score 3):

Software like [Virtual Audio Cable](http://software.muzychenko.net/eng/vac.htm) ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20170508020506/http://software.muzychenko.net/eng/vac.htm)) creates pair of virtual sound devices connected together. Configure audio player to use "output" device and voice recognition software to use "input" device.

Screenshot:

[image]

[image]

From my tests (few different "virtual audio cables") this kind of software may have some reliability problems. Why not use just physical sound card with output connected to input with jack cable (if your card does not allow to use output and input same time - buy separate $1 USB sound card)?

Comment: thanks, so far it seems to work okay. What reliability issue did you have?

Comment: (I tried it on Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate)

Comment: Various problems (either complete drop or severely disturbed audio) when running for a long time (this was intended to work 24/7 on Win10 64bit). I'm not sure if problems were not caused by DAW software though.